# Docker desktop (Windows 10) issue with Postgres docker-compose

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

On Docker Desktop (Windows 10), i'm unable to start postgres container with `docker-compose`

```
version: '3'
services:

  postgres:
     image: postgres:latest
     environment:
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD='somepassword'
       - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```

Getting error that password is not set:

```
$ docker-compose up --build
Starting complex_postgres_1 ... done
Attaching to complex_postgres_1
postgres_1  | Error: Database is uninitialized and superuser password is not specified.
postgres_1  |        You must specify POSTGRES_PASSWORD to a non-empty value for the
postgres_1  |        superuser. For example, "-e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password" on "docker run".
postgres_1  | 
postgres_1  |        You may also use "POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust" to allow all
postgres_1  |        connections without a password. This is *not* recommended.
postgres_1  |
postgres_1  |        See PostgreSQL documentation about "trust":
postgres_1  |        https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-trust.html
complex_postgres_1 exited with code 1
```

However, on Linux (CentOS 8) all works fine, even without last line `- POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust`

Has anyone experienced same issue on Windows 10 ?

Docker desktop is on latest version as well as docker-compose command

Comment: Try adding double quotes around your password. Or even the entire declaration. i.e. `"POSTGRES_PASSWORD=somepassword"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The single quote in your password is also going as a part of password

```
version: '3'
services:

  postgres:
     image: postgres:latest
     environment:
       - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=somepassword
       - POSTGRES_HOST_AUTH_METHOD=trust
```